# Option value auto run javascript on page load

Tags: javascript

So when I load the page, Week 1 is automatically the chosen option which is good, but the javascript doesn't run until I manually select an option. I would like the javascript to automatically load on week 1 but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
 <section class="Schedule">
            <form name = "form_schedule" action = "">
                <select id = "s1" name = "s1" onchange = "schedule('this.form')">
                    <option value = "Week 1" selected> Week 1 </option>
                    <option value = "Week 2"> Week 2 </option>
                    <option value = "Week 3"> Week 3 </option>
                    <option value = "Week 4"> Week 4 </option>
                    <option value = "All Weeks"> All Weeks </option>
                </select>
            </form>
                <h2> Schedule </h2>           
                    <table border = "2" id = "League_Schedule">
                        <tr>
                            <th> Home</th> 
                            <th> Result </th>               
                            <th> Away </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
        </section>
```

Comment: Looks like it happens `onchange`. You can always execute the function when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `onload` function:

```
<script>window.onload = schedule('this.form')</script>
```

Just put it before the closing body tag.